# Missing function from API - Color.RBGtoHSV

Tags: java, android, colors

I'm trying to convert RGB color to HSV in android java. I've looked up the API documents and found there is an inbuilt function to do this but I can't seem to get it to actually work. Android Studio doesn't acknowledge it exists (shows red, doesn't auto-complete) and therefore won't compile the program with a reference to it. I have included to import statement to `android.graphics.*`.

The API reference is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#RGBToHSV(int,%20int,%20int,%20float[]))

The code I've tried to far is as follows;

```
//First attempt
Color test = new Color();
test.RGBtoHSV(rgbcolor, hsvreturn);

//Second attempt
android.graphics.Color.RGBtoHSV(rgbcolor, hsvreturn);

//Third attempt
Color.RGBtoHSB(rgbcolor, hsvreturn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to use this function is this:

```
int rgb = 0xFF0000; //red

//Same but different
//int rgb = Color.RED;

float[] hsv = new float[3];

Color.RGBToHSV(Color.red(rgb),  Color.green(rgb), Color.blue(rgb), hsv);
```

Another (better) method is to use colorToHSV:

```
int rgb = 0xFF0000; //red

float[] hsv = new float[3];

Color.colorToHSV(rgb, hsv);
```

I suggest you READ the API reference next time ;)

**Update after comment:**

I spotted a few things you need to change:

1. Your class does not have a close bracket.
2. Code statements like yours needs to be inside a function or constructor.
3. Missing imports.

This would be the code your looking for:

```
import android.graphics.Color;

public class LibraryClass {

    public static void yourFunction() {

        int rgb = Color.RED;

        // This also works
        // int rgb = 0xFF0000;

        float[] hsv = new float[3];

        Color.colorToHSV(rgb, hsv);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did read the API the variables I added into the call were just placeholders. Even with your code I still get it showing in red and not compiling. As seen here. http://imageshack.com/a/img538/6905/cEnEyM.png

Comment: Ah it was the enclosing in the function. I did have the imports and closing brackets they were just cropped below the white space above and below in the photo.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the method signature wrong.

It should be:

```
RGBToHSV(int red, int green, int blue, float[] hsv)
```

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#RGBToHSV(int,%20int,%20int,%20float[])

Unless you were after this one?

```
colorToHSV(int color, float[] hsv)
```

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#colorToHSV(int,%20float[])

Note that both methods are static

Both work fine in Android Studio for me.

Comment: Siriously is this the 100 time just today someone exactly takes my answer and gets an upvote?

Comment: @RolfSmit I didn't upvote them. Your answer is more complete although still doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: @Rolf Smit - You answer hadn't even been posted at the time of my answer, look at the time stamp before accusing someone of copying you.

Comment: Sorry in that case. I'm just getting frustrated because it happens al the time. Actualy I did look at the timestamp...